# Run a command within a container within Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, containers

I have an App Service hosted in Linux running a custom container. I have my app running, but I would like to run and schedule commands at specified intervals. For simplicity sake, let's say I want to run the `ls` command every hour. There are three options that come to mind:

1. Run them within the container. Right now I have a problem that `cron` command is not there, but even if it were, will it persist? It is my understanding that containers are recreated on restarts, scale ups, etc.
2. Use any other service within Azure like Automation Jobs by executing some sort of `az` or `powershell` command that would execute the command within the container. Is there such a command? I did find one, but it was specific to Azure's Container services, not App Services.
3. Use any other service within Azure that would execute the command through SSH. Is that even possible?

Maybe another option? Something more native, like WebJobs (not available for Linux)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would just add `cron` to the container image, and then schedule the job within the container.  For example, for an Ubuntu image, add the following to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    apt-get install -y cron
```

Depending on how your container is run, you can then amend the container startup to amend the crontab and start cron, or build this into the container image.

Anything built into the container image will persist, anything that is performed whilst the container is running will not persist after a restart.